# How to specify the rendering order in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a .tsx file that renders two component:

```
export default observer(function MyModule(props: MyModuleProps) {
    ....
    return (
         <div>
             <TopPart></TopPart>
             <LowerPart></LowerPart>
         </div>
    );
});
```

The problem I have is that the TopPart contains lots of sub components, so it takes much longer time to render, and the LowerPart is more important and I want to render it first, but in this code, the LowerPart won't be available until the TopPart has been rendered.

What I want to do is to first render the LowerPart, then the TopPart, without changing the layout. I am wondering how I can achieve this goal properly.

Comment: If a component is loading more than a few milliseconds you have some major performance issue.

Comment: Yes, there is some perf improvement to make, but still, we want to first render the LowerPart, then the TopPart, so I am still wondering if this is technically possible. I tried to just reverse the order in the return statement but it would reverse the layout too, which I don't want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they render in the same time

Comment: Ah okay, I thought React rendering is single thread execution with event loop, which executes the component rendering job in a queue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop, so this is not the case and it is rendering in parallel?

Comment: By "takes much longer time to render" Do you mean that it takes a long time for the CPU to crunch out all the components because it's a huge tree of DOM nodes? Or do you mean that the data that is needed for that `TopPart` takes a long time for the server to provide?

Comment: @AlexWayne I think it's both cases. There are lots of DOM nodes in the TopPart, and the data used to populate the view is also relatively large, so we are caching the data to make follow-up renders faster, but the first time rendering is still slow. I think some improvement could be made in term of fetching the data. That's good point.

Comment: @AlexWayne So instead of improving the perf for the TopPart, I think the shortcut is perhaps to just render the LowerPart first, so I  am wondering if there is a way to possibly achieve that.

Comment: @flyingbee your question is somewhat of an XY question (https://xyproblem.info/). I would update your original question with as much detail as possible to get better help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is a hack.

If the problem is server side, this is easy for react. Just throw up a placeholder while data is loading, then save it in state when loading finishes and render.

The following answer assumes this is a rendering performance problem. If it is, then you look at that rendering performance. Paginate your lists, simplify your CSS rules, profile react and see what is taking the time.

What follows may be interesting, but is probably a bad idea. React is declarative, meaning you tell the result you want and then let it crunch things to deliver that. As soon as you start telling it what order to do things in, you break that paradigm and things may get painful for you.

---

If you want to break up rendering you *could* use state to prevent the expensive component from rendering, and then use an effect to update that state after the first render, which then renders both components.

You could make a custom hook like this:

```
function useDeferredRender(): boolean {
  const [doRender, setDoRender] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!doRender) {
      setTimeout(() => setDoRender(true), 100);
    }
  }, [doRender]);

  return doRender;
}
```

This hook create the `doRender` state, initialized to `false`. Then it has an effect which sets the state to `true` after a brief timeout. This means that `doRender` will be `false` on the first render, and then the hook will immediately set `doRender` to true, which triggers a new render.

The timeout period is tricky. Too small and React may decide to batch the render, too much and you waste time. (Did I mention this was a hack?)

You would this like so:

```
function App() {
  const renderTop = useDeferredRender();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderTop ? <TopPart /> : "..."}
      <LowerPart />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-water-ghzvte?file=/src/App.tsx)

---

One last time: this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! I can understand how it works this way. As you mentioned, the tricky part is timeout period. So, instead of using setTimeout, I am wondering if we can set a state (e.g finishedRenderLowerPart) in the useEffect of the LowerPart, which indicates if LowerPart has been rendered or not. Then, in the TopPart, we can do something like {lowerPartFinishedRender ? <TopPart /> : "...."}

Comment: That probably won't help. The timeout here won't even start until a full render has completed. Remember the whole page is rendered everytime. The lower part doesn't render first. The whole page renders without the top part, and then the page render including the top part. That's just how react works.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned that "Too small and React may decide to batch the render", that's interesting. Does it mean React will render TopPart and LowerPart together, in which case, it will render TopPart first?

Comment: React does not stream its rendering to the screen. React renders everything on the page, and when done presents everything it rendered all at once. It does happen to do that top to bottom, but you'd never be able to tell from the outside. If `TopPart` is expensive to render, then the problem you will see is that the whole page lags takes a long time to render. So yes, it renders `TopPart` first, but that doesn't matter. You could move it to the bottom to make it render last, and the result would be exactly the same.